# The bounce effect in jquery is not working ideally

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want create element which will appear with bounce effect and this effect should run all time while user not clicking to `help_man`, when its happened effect is completed. Now its work, but not prefer, effect run slow and eventually faster and faster. Bounce does not always stop on mouse click event.
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ArthurYakovlev/9nEne/)
HTML:

```
<div class='task_wrapper'>
<div class='help_man'>
<img src='images/cow.png'/>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script src="js/jquery-ui-bounce.min.js"></script>
<script>
var to_stop = 0;
function run_bounce()
{
    if(to_stop==0)
    {
        $(".task_wrapper").effect( "bounce", "fast" );
        setInterval(run_bounce,3000);
    }else{
        return;
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".help_man").click(function() {
        to_stop = 1;
    });
    run_bounce();
});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to clear the interval,

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9nEne/13/

**JS**

```
var to_stop = 0, interval;
function run_bounce() {
    if(to_stop==0)
    {
        $(".task_wrapper").effect( "bounce", "fast" );
        clearInterval(interval);
        console.log(interval);
        interval = setInterval(run_bounce,3000);
    }else{
        $(".task_wrapper").stop();
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".help_man").click(function() {
        to_stop = 1;
    });
    run_bounce();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add positon as abosulte in CSS.That is way we animate DOM elements on fly.
Alway best pratices to `clearInterval` before call setInterVal(); which return number.

```
.task_wrapper{
    postion:absolute;
}

var to_stop = 0,interval;
function run_bounce()
{
    if(to_stop==0)
    {
        $(".task_wrapper").effect( "bounce", "fast" );
         clearInterval(interval);
         interval = setInterval(run_bounce,3000);
        setInterval(run_bounce,3000);
    }else{
         $(".task_wrapper").stop(); //Note here stop()       
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".help_man").click(function() {
        to_stop = 1;       
    });
    run_bounce();
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9nEne/16/)

Comment: This doesnt work, you have mearly changed the size of the element by using text. See http://jsfiddle.net/9nEne/3/

Comment: This script is still accelerates with time animation work. And not always the animation stops when pressing it. Property postion:absolute; attending, but thanks!

Comment: But still eventually accelerated animation. And strange behavior.